# How to alter views page attachments

Tags: views, theming, 8

I want to remove the

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/taxonomie_term_url">
```

From my `<head>` section

and  add

```
<link rel="next" href="base_url?page=1" />
```

on the first page

```
<link rel="prev" href="base_url" />
<link rel="next" href="base_url?page=2" />
```

on the second

and on the last page only

```
<link rel="prev" href="base_url?page={x}" />
```

I tried to do it in a page_attachment_alter() hook but there were no view attachments.
Than I tried to do it in a view pre_render / post_render / pre_build / post_build hook. I'm pretty sure this is the false tendency, though.

```
if($view->current_display == 'block_pager') {
  $links = $view->getBaseEntityType()->get('links');
  if (array_key_exists('canonical', $links)) {
    $links =  array_filter($links, function ($link) {
      return $link !== 'canonical';
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $view->getBaseEntityType()->set('links', $links);
  }
}
```

But that gives me

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\UndefinedLinkTemplateException: No link template 'canonical' found for the 'node' entity type in Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->toUrl() (line 214 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php).
Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController->view(Object, 'full', NULL)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 144)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 64)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 652)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

And adding those rel"next/prev" stuff
I tried to include them in my html.html.twig but I have no pager context there.

I have found a solution about those next/prev stuff

```
global $pager_total, $pager_page_array;
  $current_path = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
  $path = $current_path->toString();
  if ($path == '/startseite') {
    $path = '/';
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] == 1) {
    $prev = '';
  }
  else {
    $prev = '?page=' . $page = $pager_page_array[0] - 1;
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] == 0) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'next',
        'href' => $path . '?page=' . $next = $pager_page_array[0]+1,
      ],
    ], 'rel_next_first'];
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] != 0 && $pager_page_array[0]+1 != $pager_total[0]) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'next',
        'href' => $path . '?page=' . $next = $pager_page_array[0]+1,
      ],
    ], 'rel_next'];
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'prev',
        'href' => $path . $prev,
      ],
    ], 'rel_prev'];
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0]+1 == $pager_total[0]) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'prev',
        'href' => $path . $prev,
      ],
    ], 'rel_prev_last'];
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] > 0) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'canonical',
        'href' => $path . '?page=' . $pager_page_array[0],
      ],
    ], 'canonical_url'];
  }
```

This is the the point where this ghost `<link rel="canonical">` is created. At Line 69 NodeViewController::view()

```
 if ($this->currentUser->isAuthenticated() || $url->access($this->currentUser)) {
   // Set the node path as the canonical URL to prevent duplicate content.
   $build['#attached']['html_head_link'][] = [[
     'rel' => $rel,
     'href' => $url->toString(),
   ], TRUE,];
 }
```

Now if I wrap this snippet with

```
if (rel !== 'canonical') {}
```

It works and that ghost attachment is gone.
But hacking core is real evil, so how do I achieve this in a clean or almost clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add next and prev link tags to your add use a page_attachment_alter hook.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function my_module_base_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {      
  global $pager_total, $pager_page_array;
  $current_path = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
  $path = $current_path->toString();
  if ($path == '/startseite') {
    $path = '/';
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] == 1) {
    $prev = '';
  }
  else {
    $prev = '?page=' . $page = $pager_page_array[0] - 1;
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] == 0) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'next',
        'href' => $path . '?page=' . $next = $pager_page_array[0]+1,
      ],
    ], 'rel_next_first'];
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0] != 0 && $pager_page_array[0]+1 != $pager_total[0]) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'next',
        'href' => $path . '?page=' . $next = $pager_page_array[0]+1,
      ],
    ], 'rel_next'];
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'prev',
        'href' => $path . $prev,
      ],
    ], 'rel_prev'];
  }
  if ($pager_page_array[0]+1 == $pager_total[0]) {
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [[
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'link',
      '#attributes' => [
        'rel' => 'prev',
        'href' => $path . $prev,
      ],
    ], 'rel_prev_last'];
  }  
}
```

For that duplicate canonical I had to alter the entity.node.canonical route controller...

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Class RouteSubscriber.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mylife_base\Routing
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $hmm = $collection;
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
      $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\NodeViewController::view');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to replace : `$current_path = Url::fromRoute('<current>’);` by `$current_path = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>’);` And I need to disable cache in Views otherwise the module didn’t update the attribute.